# False instead of True (@gmail.com)

Tags: java, class, oop, authentication

I wrote an authenticator to see if an email ends with "@gmail.com".
I don't really know why is this returns false.
Could someone help me out why is it?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println(StringUtils.isValidGmail("a@gmail.com"));  // true
}


public static boolean isValidGmail(String email){
    if (email == null){
        return false;
    }
    int x = email.length() - 1;
    String gmail = email.substring(x-9, x+1);  // @gmail.com
    return gmail == "@gmail.com";
}
```

Comment: for string comparison use .equals() not == they do two separate type of checks.

Comment: try `return gmail.equals("@gmail.com");` Read of course the link in the above comment for the explanation [-:

Comment: Ohh okay thank you very much

Comment: `return email.endsWith("@gmail.com")` could be a one-liner.

Comment: Ok I’ll read that thanks a lot

Comment: Ohh thanks .endsWith is better

Comment: in addition there is another method exists for this particular problem. You don't event need to find the email part.
Try, `if (email == null){
            return false;
    }
    return gmail.endsWith( "@gmail.com")`

Comment: Yes Ivar already said that, but thanks for your help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should  replace `return gmail == "@gmail.com";` by `return gmail.equals("@gmail.com");`

Comment: Ok I see thank you very much